# Fit a distribution from quantiles

Tags: python, statistics, bayesian, pymc3, pymc

I'm trying to [replicate an example](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2018/03/07/fit-distribution-matching-quantile.html) from SAS in Python where I fit a distribution from summary statistics. The summary statistics available to me are the total count, min, max, p50, p75, p85, p95, p98, p99, and p99.9. The measurements are coming from a distributed network of machines and consist of either latency or size distributions. The goal is to re-construct the mixture from each machine, and then combine those distributions to estimate the distribution of the entire network and do this on a regular interval in a streaming fashion.

I'm looking through the documentation of [PyMC](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc), [Pyro](https://github.com/pyro-ppl/numpyro) and [Pomegranate](https://github.com/jmschrei/pomegranate) and get the general gist of mixture models, but the thing that I don't understand is how to setup the initial parameters for each distribution, which one to use given the data available to me, or how to shift each distribution to the corresponding quantile to construct the overall distribution.

Is this possible given any of these frameworks?

Comment: You could fit a distribution from the given data for each machine, and then compute a joint distribution from them (what sort of dependencies would you want to include?). It'll depend on the quantiles and number of observations you have which distributions fit each machine best.

Comment: Yeah, that's the general idea. TBH what I'm struggling with is the API and documentation of the frameworks given my limited statistics knowledge. They're written for statisticians and not very approachable.

Comment: My first thought is to fit parameters for a distribution by Kullback-Leibler difference (a form of cross-entropy) or something like that between the given quantiles and the fitted distribution. I think there are some basic questions about organizing the solution that you need to work out before going into the code -- my advice is to take up this question on stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The data are not clear to me yet. Do you have summary statistics per machine or for the entire ensemble? Could you please post a small data sample that can serve as a starting point? - more details might be helpful and would increase the quality of the answer.

Comment: The summary stats available to me are for each individual machine. The desire is to come up with a set summary stats for the entire ensemble knowing only these summary stats. Essentially create a mixture for the entire ensemble knowing the summary stats for each population and then get the summary stats for the combined pop.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Answering my own question with some help from the [Pyro forums](https://forum.pyro.ai/t/fit-a-distribution-from-quantiles/1491). The code below contains the solution to the first half of the problem, finding a distribution that matches the parameters from the collected quantiles:

```
import torch
import torch.distributions as dist
from torch.optim import Adam

from typing import List, Tuple


def find_cauchy_params(quantiles: List[Tuple[float, float]]):
    alpha = torch.tensor(1.0, requires_grad=True)
    beta = torch.tensor(1.0, requires_grad=True)

    quantile_tensors = [
        (quantile, torch.tensor(quantile_value))
        for quantile, quantile_value in quantiles
    ]

    def loss_fn():
        loss = 0.0
        d = dist.Cauchy(alpha, beta)
        for quantile, quantile_value in quantile_tensors:
            loss += (quantile - d.cdf(quantile_value)) ** 2

        return loss

    optim = Adam([alpha, beta], lr=0.01)
    for step in range(1000):
        optim.zero_grad()
        loss = loss_fn()
        print("loss", loss)
        loss.backward()
        optim.step()

    print("alpha = {}".format(alpha.item()))
    print("beta = {}".format(beta.item()))


find_cauchy_params(
    [(0.5, 0.0), (0.75, 0.0), (0.95, 1.0), (0.98, 1.0), (0.99, 8.0), (0.999, 11.0)]
)
```

Truncated Output:

```
...
loss tensor(0.0317, grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
loss tensor(0.0317, grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
loss tensor(0.0317, grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
loss tensor(0.0317, grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
alpha = -0.04828706011176109
beta = 0.11657208949327469
```